# BinaryWriter Endian issue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, endianness

I am using BinaryWriter class to write a binary file to disk. When I invoke the Write method, passing an unsigned short value, it writes it in little-endian format. For example:

```
bw.Write(0xA000);
```

writes the value in the binary file as 0x00 0xA0. Is there a way to make BInaryWriter use Big Endian? If not, is it possible to create a new class, inheriting BinaryWriter and overload the Write function to make it write big endian?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use my `EndianBinaryWriter` in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil). That lets you specify the endianness you want. There's also `EndianBinaryReader` and `EndianBitConverter`.

```
EndianBinaryWriter writer = new EndianBinaryWriter(EndianBitConverter.Big,
                                                   stream);
writer.Write(...);
```

It doesn't derive from `BinaryWriter`, for reasons [given in a blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/03/16/breaking-liskov.aspx).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need (although my project is .NET 2.0). I will try it out! Thanks!

Comment: There's a .NET 2.0 version of MiscUtil which you can download - it should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I know this post is 5 years old, but your blog post link is dead :/

Answer (score 3):

according to microsoft connect, it's currently not supported: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=484149