# Does SQL Server 2005 SSIS Support UTF-16BE (Big Endian)?

Tags: sql-server-2005, encoding, ssis, endianness, utf-16

According to [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/8c2a1c56-2889-47b2-bee3-5b5651b9ec72), SSIS only supports UTF-16 Little Endian flat files.  Is that true for all files?  I want to load a UTF-16 BE XML file through SSIS.  Is that supported/possible?

Comment: I can't give a 100% authoritative answer as I'm an ignorant American who doesn't deal with internationalization. What I do know is that SSIS supports the .NET framework for data sources and destinations. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue) indicates .NET supports reading/writing to bigendian files so you could always roll your own reader/writer source. I *think* once in the pipeline, it's just character data (DT_WSTR) and subject to manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a UTF-16BE encoded XML file and ran a simple import task in SSIS and it worked just fine.  I'm not sure the motivation behind handling flat files differently, but I suppose it has something to do with legacy code.

UPDATE: I ran this on SSIS 2008.  Installing SSIS 2005 to confirm.
UPDATE: I confirmed this works on SSIS 2005 also.