# Helpful byte array extensions to handle BigEndian data

Tags: c#, arrays

I recently came across the issue of needing to frequently (& easily) convert & extract bytes from a BigEndian byte array that was being received over TCP.  For those unfamiliar with Big/Little Endian, the short version is that each number was sent as MSB then LSB.

When processing and extracting values from the byte array using the default BitConverter on a Little Endian system (read: just about any C#/windows machine), this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some handy extension methods that I created in my project that I thought I would share with fellow readers.  The trick here is to only reverse the bytes required for the requested data size.

As a bonus, the byte[ ] extension methods makes the code tidy (in my opinion).

Comments & improvements are welcome.

Syntax to use:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
var uint16bigend = bytes.GetUInt16BigE(2);    // MSB-LSB ... 03-04 = 772
var uint16bitconv = bytes.GetUInt16(2);       // LSB-MSB ... 04-03 = 1027
```

Here is the class with the initial set of extensions.  Easy for readers to extend & customize:

```
public static class BitConverterExtensions
{
    public static UInt16 GetUInt16BigE(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    }

    public static UInt32 GetUInt32BigE(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    }

    public static Int16 GetInt16BigE(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    }

    public static Int32 GetInt32BigE(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    }

    public static UInt16 GetUInt16(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, startIndex);
    }

    public static UInt32 GetUInt32(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, startIndex);
    }

    public static Int16 GetInt16(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, startIndex);
    }

    public static Int32 GetInt32(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, startIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at using an endian-aware BinaryReader/BinaryWriter implemention. Here are links to some:

- [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540269/467473) to the question, [BinaryWriter Endian issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue)
- [Anculus.Core.IO](https://code.google.com/p/libanculus-sharp/source/browse/trunk/src/Anculus.Core/IO/) has an endian-aware `BinaryReader`, `BinaryWriter` and `BitConverter`: https://code.google.com/p/libanculus-sharp/source/browse/trunk/src/Anculus.Core/IO/?r=227
- The Iso-Parser project (parser for parsing ISO disk images) has an [endian-aware `BitConverter`](https://code.google.com/p/iso-parser/source/browse/trunk/EndianBitConverter.cs)
- [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (Rabbit Message Queue) has an big-endian [`BinaryReader`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/util/NetworkBinaryReader.cs) and [`BinaryWriter`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/util/NetworkBinaryWriter.cs) on Github at https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client.

Comment: Nice links, good to know.  Issue with the readers (in my case) is that it implies I know what I'm reading from the stream ahead of time.  In my case, I have an array in memory (based on record delimiters + length) that was ingested, then different subclasses will interpret the byte array differently and extract different combinations.  The Anculus lib does indeed have a BitConverter that does the trick too.