# Converting an amount to a 4 byte array

Tags: c#

I haven't ever had to deal with this before. I need to convert a sale amount (48.58) to a 4 byte array and use network byte order. The code below is how I am doing it, but it is wrong and I am not understanding why. Can anyone help?

```
float saleamount = 48.58F; 
byte[] data2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(saleamount).Reverse().ToArray();
```

What I am getting is 66 66 81 236 in the array. I am not certain what it should be though. I am interfacing with a credit card terminal and need to send the amount in "4 bytes, fixed length, max value is 0xffffffff, use network byte order"

Comment: "I am not certain what it should be though."... so how do you know it is wrong? looks pretty legit to me ;-) or: does it expect an integer representing the number (treating the float as a fixed fixed point value)?

Comment: Also, can I recommend instead of blindly using Reverse(), to check BitConverter.IsLittleEndian first?

Comment: Are you certain that the terminal is expecting an IEEE single?  If I were designing a credit card terminal, I would not use that data type.

Comment: Also consider [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1(v=vs.110).aspx).  That is, assuming this interface was written correctly to not use floating-point monetary values.

Comment: What's the maximum monetary value the protocol accepts?  For example, this assertion succeeds: `Assert.AreEqual(1000000.0f, 1000000.01f);`.  If you are processing values of that magnitude, you *can't* be using IEEE single to represent the values.

Comment: In testing the 66 66 81 236 ended up being over 8 million dollars. I believe I have to remove the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question you should ask is, "What data type?" IEEE single-precision float? Twos-complement integer? It's an integer, what is the implied scale? Is $48.53 represented as `4,853` or `485,300`?

It's not uncommon for monetary values to be represented by an integer with an implied scale of either +2 or +4. In your example, $48.58 would be represented as the integer value `4858`  or `0x000012FA`.

Once you've established what they actually want...use an endian-aware BitConverter or BinaryWriter to create it. [Jon Skeet's MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), for instance offers:

- `EndianBinaryReader`
- `EndianBinaryWriter`
- `BigEndianBitConverter`
- `LittleEndianBitConverter`

There are other implementations out there as well. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005086/467473) to the question "[Helpful byte array extensions to handle BigEndian data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004507/helpful-byte-array-extensions-to-handle-bigendian-data)" for links to some.

Code you don't write it code you don't have to maintain.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I am in the process of testing without using a decimal point in the value. I will update once I get results.

Comment: That was it sir! I need to remove the decimal point. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Network byte order pseudo-synonym of big-endian, hence (as itsme86 mentioned already) so you can check BitConverter.IsLittleEndian:

```
        float saleamount = 48.58F;
        byte[] data2 = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
            ? BitConverter.GetBytes(saleamount).Reverse().ToArray()
            : BitConverter.GetBytes(saleamount);
```

But if you don't know this, probably you already using some protocol, which handle it.