# ByteArray class for C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, arrays

I'm trying to translate a function from ActionScript 3 into C# .NET.

What I have trouble is how to properly use ByteArrays in C#. In As3 there is a specific Class for it that already has most of the functionality i need, but in C# nothing of that sort seems to exist and I can't wrap my head around it.

This is the As3 function:

```
private function createBlock(type:uint, tag:uint,data:ByteArray):ByteArray
        {
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            ba.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
            ba.writeUnsignedInt(data.length+16);
            ba.writeUnsignedInt(0x00);
            ba.writeUnsignedInt(type);
            ba.writeUnsignedInt(tag);
            data.position = 0;
            ba.writeBytes(data);
            ba.position = 0;

            return ba;  
        }
```

But from what I gather, in C# I have to use a normal Array with the byte type, like this

```
byte[] ba = new byte[length];
```

Now, I looked into the Encoding Class, the BinaryWriter and BinaryFormatter class and researched if somebody made a Class for ByteArrays, but with no luck.

Can somebody nudge me in the right direction please?

Comment: What is the function trying to do? there may be better alternatives

Comment: Take a look at the Stream class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Sayse It's adding a header to the byte array that defines some meta information.

Comment: @DodgerThud - I meant what are you attempting to do with that byte array, you may find there are other classes that can be used instead (i.e the stream class already shown)

Comment: @Sayse The ByteArray will be later sent through a socket to a device.

Comment: You may wish to take a look around for alternatives also, such as [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx), best of luck anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a combination of `MemoryStream` and `BinaryWriter`:

```
public static byte[] CreateBlock(uint type, uint tag, byte[] data)
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // We want 'BinaryWriter' to leave 'memory' open, so we need to specify false for the third
        // constructor parameter. That means we need to also specify the second parameter, the encoding.
        // The default encoding is UTF8, so we specify that here.

        var defaultEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier:false, throwOnInvalidBytes:true);

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(memory, defaultEncoding, leaveOpen:true))
        {
            // There is no Endian - things are always little-endian.

            writer.Write((uint)data.Length+16);
            writer.Write((uint)0x00);
            writer.Write(type);
            writer.Write(data);
        }

        // Note that we must close or flush 'writer' before accessing 'memory', otherwise the bytes written
        // to it may not have been transferred to 'memory'.

        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

However, note that `BinaryWriter` always uses little-endian format. If you need to control this, you can use [Jon Skeet's `EndianBinaryWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540269/106159) instead.

As an alternative to this approach, you could pass streams around instead of byte arrays (probably using a `MemoryStream` for implementation), but then you will need to be careful about lifetime management, i.e. who will close/dispose the stream when it's done with? (You might be able to get away with not bothering to close/dispose a memory stream since it uses no unmanaged resources, but that's not entirely satisfactory IMO.)

Comment: Thanks, your previous answer was already perfect. But thanks for adding an alternative approach. I got it working just the way I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a byte stream and then extract the array from it:

```
using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memory))
{
    // write  into stream
    writer.Write((byte)0); // a byte
    writer.Write(0f);      // a float
    writer.Write("hello"); // a string

    return memory.ToArray(); // returns the underlying array
}
```

Comment: This also works but Matthew was a tad faster and provided more info. But thank you for you help.