# C# BinaryWriter buffer for sending segments?

Tags: java, c#, input, output, binarywriter

I'm not sure that a "Buffer" is what I'm looking for, so I'll show you my problem and then you guys can decide if that's the correct word and on a solution. Currently I'm working on creating a networking port for the Java DataOutputStream class in C#. The last thing I have to do is fix this issue with sending segmented information.

Here's my **WriteInt** method in C# (**ClientOutput is an instance of BinaryWriter**)

```
public void WriteInt(int v)
{
    ClientOutput.Write (((uint)v >> 24) & 0xFF);
    ClientOutput.Write (((uint)v >> 16) & 0xFF);
    ClientOutput.Write (((uint)v >> 8) & 0xFF);
    ClientOutput.Write (((uint)v >> 0) & 0xFF);
    IncCount (4);
}
```

For anyone who wants to compare; here's the original in **Java**

```
public final void writeInt(int v) throws IOException {
       out.write((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
       out.write((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
       out.write((v >>>  8) & 0xFF);
       out.write((v >>>  0) & 0xFF);
       incCount(4);
}
```

Normally in java you would have to call "**Flush()**" before the data would be sent to the server or client; However it appears that the BinaryWriter automatically flushes whenever you call "**Write()**"

Here's the "**ReadInt()**" code in Java.

```
public final int readInt() throws IOException {
        int ch1 = in.read();
        int ch2 = in.read();
        int ch3 = in.read();
        int ch4 = in.read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

When the Java code is executed to "**WriteInt**" and **ReadInt** is called on the server, the value is displayed properly; However currently the server is processing the integer 4 different times and displaying an integer value based on the segments.

Example Input (**C#**):

```
Client.WriteInt(1000);
```

Example output(**Java**):

```
0
0
50331648
-402653184
```

When the output should be:

```
1000
```

Please bear with me as I just picked up C# a few days ago, and I may be asking a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BinaryWriter has a bunch of Write() method overloads and it looks like you are calling the Write(Int32) overload, which of course sends four 4-byte integers.

You should be able to fix the problem simply by casting your values to byte in the call to Write():

```
public void WriteInt(int v)
{
    ClientOutput.Write ((byte)(((uint)v >> 24) & 0xFF));
    ClientOutput.Write ((byte)(((uint)v >> 16) & 0xFF));
    ClientOutput.Write ((byte)(((uint)v >> 8) & 0xFF));
    ClientOutput.Write ((byte)(((uint)v >> 0) & 0xFF));
    IncCount (4);
}
```

Note that technically speaking, you should not need to cast the value v to uint before the shift. Even if sign-extension were to occur, you're masking off all but the last byte anyway. But that part shouldn't hurt anything.

Check out Jon Skeet's endian-aware version of BinaryWriter. There's discussion and some links here: [BinaryWriter Endian issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue)

Comment: The only reason I was casting to `uint` was because the original library that's written in java was using unsigned shifts. I figured there was a reason for it so I kept their methods. I'll try this once I get home and see if it works.