# C# binary writer ushort bytes order

Tags: c#, memorystream, binarywriter, bytestream

I have a server side app written in D and my client app is written in C#. I use BinaryWriter for communication between them but I have a problem with the byte order.

Actually the order of bytes is not the same, example :

C# Client:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);
writer.Write((ushort)0x01);
writer.Write("test");
```

Client Output:

```
[1, 0, 4, 116, 101, 115, 116]
```

Server output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 4, 116, 101, 115, 116]
```

For the client the first 2 bytes have been inverted and the string in my server app is encoded with `ushort` for length, it is possible to 'modify' the behavior of the BinaryWriter or do I have to create my own implementation?

Edit: Server side the packet serializer: https://github.com/Adwelean/EmperadorServer/blob/master/source/vendor/cerealed/cerealiser.d

Comment: its not inverted. one zero is added first

Comment: If i write a ushort with the server the byte array is [0, 1] and with the client the byte array is [1, 0]

Comment: i think the server uses big endian order and the client uses little endian order ...

Comment: @Adwelean in that example there is a 0 prepended, again. Without seeing the server code there is nothing that can be said to help you. You seem to be aware that this *might* be an endianness issue. Closing.

Comment: i think too but why the string was not reverted ? ^^

Comment: The answer lies in the server code which you have not posted so far.

Comment: You need to reverse array if machine is using LittleEndian. To check we have `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`. if true reverse.

Comment: It does not look like an endian issue. Hard to say exactly because the 2 samples are not even of the same length.

Comment: @Henk Holterman the BinaryWriter write string length has byte it is for that the 2 sample are not the same length

Comment: Yes, that has changed I think. The docs say the length "is written as an unsigned integer" but that isn't true. It's a variable length prefix.

Comment: But that means you have another incompatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MSDN document, BinaryWriter stores UInt16 in little endian format. So it is possible to have a reversed written byte order.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sh9zw1e(v=vs.110).aspx

I think you can refer to this post for how to use big endian for the writer.

[BinaryWriter Endian issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue)